# how to invoke injected bean's method

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a question about how to invoke methods of bean injected in Spring framework.

The injected class is consisted of setter, getter, and properties. It would like this:

```
class Mark {
   private String opacity;
   private String alignment;

   public setOpacity(String opacity);
   public getOpacity();
   public setAlignement(String alignement);
   public getAlignement();
}
```

This class will be injected to another class, and I want to get data like opacity, alignment from class Mark. However I don't want to write the class's method name in caller class like this:

```
@Autowired
Mark mark;

void caller() {

    String opacity = mark.getOpacity();

    String alignment = mark.getAlignment(); 
 }
```

For this, I thought about reflection using Class.forName(), getDeclaredFields(), getDeclaredMethods(), but I soon realised that it works for normal class not fot the injected class.

So my question is:
Is there any way to invoke the injected bean's methods or get data directly using reflection? or any idea get data from the injected bean?

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection? Isn't it enough just to call ```mark.getOpacity()``` or ```mark.getAlignment()```? By the way, your getter method definition definitions are wrong and, considering you are using annotation, you should also annotate Mark class as @Service, @Component or similar.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must specify returned type of your methods in `Mark`:

```
public void setOpacity(String opacity);
public String getOpacity();
public void setAlignement(String alignement);
public String getAlignement();
```

Then, you must annotate your `Mark` class with `@Service`

Comment: I am sorry to forget to add return type of methods in Mark. I also know use @service annotation but I thought it isn't important for this because I mentioned "This class will be injected" and I will make it. For this, nobody comments for my real question except indicating usage.